# Angular ng-click multiple functions

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-click="method1(); method2()> </div>
```

Here if the method1() calls the database / external service and gets the data. And method2() is some other behavior execution like UI bindings.
Suppose in case if there is a delay in getting the data from method1(), how to avoid or stop execution of method2() until method1() execution completes.

Note: I can't add method2() call from method1() due to some restrictions. Also I want to execute both these methods from the ng-click only.

Comment: ajax goes asyc so you must consider using its callback function .you cannot have 2 function calls in `ng-click` .

Comment: Use `$q.defer()` to assign an asynchronous callback. Perhaps you need to do it in `method3()` where you merge them and resolve your Promises

Comment: I've read your note but looks like your method2() depends on method1() so it's recommended to call it from the method1() itself using conditional structure.

Comment: Is anything stopping you from writing a single new function which will call method1() and method2() and call that single function from ng-click?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `$timeout`:

```
<div ng-click="method1()"></div>   
$scope.method1=function() {
    // calls the database / external service
    $timeout(function () {
        method2();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: `method1` is **asynchronous**, meaning it can take from few milliseconds to few minutes of processing. You can't just wait for it a specific / hardcoded amount of time. It should be resolved as a Promise (with a `$q` service) instead

Answer (score 1):

Call the method 2 in response of method1, like this

```
function method1() {
    service.getData().then(function(response) {
        //got the response here, do the operation and call method2 here
        method2()
    }, function() {});
}
```

If you call it giving any timeout, then it is not a sure solution. So call it in response.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
function method1() {
    API.getData().then(function(response) {
        // call method2 here after you receive response
        method2()
    }, function(error) {});
}
```

html

```
<div ng-click="method1()> </div>
```